# MQTT user/password not recognized in docker env

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, mqtt

I am playing with a MQTT docker-compose env and trying to use a username and password in the subscriber. Without the password both publish and subscribe work correctly.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mqtt:
   image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
   container_name: mqtt
   network_mode: bridge
   ports:
     - 1883:1883
   volumes:
     - ./conf:/mosquitto/config
     - ./log:/mosquitto/log
```

My mosquitto.conf in /mosquitto/config/ on the container looks like this:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/passwd.txt
```

My password file is in /mosquitto/config/passwd.txt and has a line with username and a clear password. I shelled into the container to the location of this file and did this

```
mosquitto_passwd -U /mosquitto/config/passwd.txt
```

which encrypts the file in place. When I look at the passwd.txt it has an entry with encrypted text:

user:$7$101$vOlxOuwvzHmJiYWC$N8MKHb4fczMZNPzCBfXK4k7mUbOp+PzwT2Yb4IeU1KMKABP8hOsvDjqe+DcK7q6ksVuGmdODfWjrjQNAfJMjZw==

When I run the publish it works fine. Along these lines:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_publish(client,userdata,result):
   print("[PUB] Data published = %s" % result)

mqtt_broker ="localhost"
client = mqtt.Client("test")
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.connect(mqtt_broker, 1883)

for i in range(10):
   temp = i
   client.publish("Temp", temp)
   print("[PUB] Just published %.4f to topic Temp" % temp)
   time.sleep(1)
```

The subscribe however never gets it:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
username='user'
password='passwd'

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
   print("[SUB] received message: %s" % message.payload.decode("utf-8"))

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("[SUB] Connected with result code "+str(rc))
   client.subscribe("/Temp")

mqtt_broker = "localhost"

client = mqtt.Client("sub")
ttl = 120
client.username_pw_set(username, password)
client.connect(mqtt_broker, 1883, ttl)

client.loop_start()

client.subscribe("Temp")
print("[SUB] Awaiting notifications")
client.loop_forever()
```

In the logs I see not authorised errors:

```
1670429277: New connection from 172.17.0.1:59538 on port 1883.
1670429277: Client mac disconnected, not authorised.
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Double check your config file, you appear to be missing a leading `/` on the `password_file` line

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that is not it. I tried it. If the password file is bad, I would see an error in the path to the password file.

Comment: Can you please turn the code above into a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. provide a `passwd.txt` and make the python stand-alone including a username/password etc). Currently the cause of your issue could run from a typo in your `passwd.txt` through to a bug in mosquitto; being able to replicate the issue ourselves makes it easier to assist you (I am surprised that your publish code works as you do not appear to be providing a username/password at all).

Comment: Ok I just did that. It should have everything I am doing

Comment: First, not authorized is different than username/password, you need to add to your ACL file to allow all on that user or for all users.
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/topic-restriction-mosquitto-configuration/

Second: The client disconnection is unclear as to which client was not authorized so for best practice, use an on_connect hook and print out what is going on: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/client-connections-python-mqtt/

Comment: When I use on_connect() in my sub I see a result of 5 (unauthorized apparently). I was not able to understand the ACL stuff, I see no default ACL file anywhere on the container

Comment: See my answer - the repeating messages are probably because you have multiple network loops running (`client.loop_start()` and `client.loop_forever()`). You should not need an ACL file if all you want to do is limit who can connect.

Comment: Thanks, actually I dont have both loop_start() and loop_forever() only the latter, I probably slipped up when editing. Can you tell me what the pythondocker is for? Do I need it if I run python locally?

Comment: You can do either - I don't use python that frequently so generally run python apps in containers  (means I don't need to have python setup locally). So `pythondocker` is just a container that I am using to run your code. Note that your comment shows how important it is that you copy/paste your exact code (even small changes can have a major impact).

Comment: One other thing I would note is that the log entry you gave included the client ID "mac" (`Client mac disconnected`) but none of the code you provided uses that ID. As such I suspect this error is due to something else connecting to the broker...

Comment: I dont understand what the difference is between yours and mine. The only difference might be that I ran it with python sub.py & (in the background)  and then ran python pub.py. I am not familiar with mosquitto_pub.exe - is it a windows tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250250/discussion-between-brits-and-user2399453).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments the issue in this case was that your "publish" did not set the username and password (but you do in your subscribe code). It's worth using a known good program (e.g. `mosquitto_sub`/`mosquitto_pub`) when testing (otherwise you might have bugs in both your subscribe and publish code which makes debugging confusing!). I'll leave the rest of my answer in case it helps anyone else.

I have been able to run your code successfully after making a few tweaks. This may not be a full answer because I have not been able to replicate your issue, but can point you towards code that works.

The main issue I can see in your code is that you are not configuring `client` to use your callbacks. e.g.:

```
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
```

This means that your program will not subscribe (and would do nothing with any messages received).

In addition to the above you are using both the threaded and blocking loop functions. This will cause issues because you end up running multiple instances of the network loop. I fixed these issues and made a few other small changes:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

username='user'
password='passwd'

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("[SUB] received message: %s" % message.payload.decode("utf-8"))

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("[SUB] Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("/Temp")

time.sleep(5)# Allow time for mosquitto to startup

mqtt_broker = "mqtt"

client = mqtt.Client("sub")
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
ttl = 120
client.username_pw_set(username, password)
client.connect(mqtt_broker, 1883, ttl)

#client.loop_start() # Pick either threaded or non-threaded, not both!

client.subscribe("Temp")
print("[SUB] Awaiting notifications")
client.loop_forever()
```

I ran your code and mosquitto using docker - config follows (happy to add `Dockerfile` etc if needed):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/mosquitto/config
      - ./log:/mosquitto/log
  pythondocker:
    image: pythondocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

With this running I used `mosquitto_pub.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -P passwd -t Temp -m "foo"` on the host to send a message which was successfully received.

```
Attaching to pythondocker-mqtt-1, pythondocker-pythondocker-1
pythondocker-pythondocker-1  | [SUB] Awaiting notifications
pythondocker-pythondocker-1  | [SUB] Connected with result code 0
pythondocker-pythondocker-1  | [SUB] received message: foo
```

If I modify the python, changing the pasword to `passwd2` then I do get the error you were seeing (not sure why you are getting this - I am using the `passwd.txt` you provided):

```
1670453773: New connection from 172.26.0.2:40037 on port 1883.
1670453773: Client sub disconnected, not authorised.
```

Comment: My problem was that I did not use the username and password in the publisher. If I do the same as in the subscriber the errors go away and the pub/sub start working as expected

Comment: I noted that in my first comment :-). This is where using a known good tool (e.g. `mosquitto_sub`) is worthwhile; knowing that one side of the conversation is working means you can better trace the real issue (and helps provide sufficient info for us to help).

Comment: If you add that to the answer I can accept it (for others who might run into something similar..)